# internal links in css sidebar

Tags: css, html

I have a web page with a "sticky" header and sidebar. Each has navigation in it. I also have a footer. How can I put internal `nav` links in the sidebar?

When I try putting either internal or external links in the `sidenav` neither of the links will work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/247t1aW3b/wMZ8V/)

Answer (score 1):

You have the `z-index` of the `#side_nav` set to `-1`. A negative value will prevent the element from being clickable. Change it to `0` or higher.

```
z-index: 0;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GmCde/)

Comment: You could just add something like: 
   `#footer {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}`

Comment: If I use relative, there's a gap between the footer and the bottom of the page. I have to use fixed I guess. Also I can't seam to get the text in the footer to center vertically.

Comment: I could help you with all these issues, but I think it's beyond the scope of the actual question, which I think I answered for you.